# Node.js chmod not working on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

In Node.js (v0.10.22) on Ubuntu, if I run `fs.chmodSync('/dir', 0777);` this doesn't actually seem to work.  Instead of setting the directory to 777 it sets it to 755.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

Thank you!

Comment: what does `fs.chmodSync` return?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the source at /lib/fs.js on line 508

```
fs.chmodSync = function(path, mode) {
  return binding.chmod(pathModule._makeLong(path), modeNum(mode));
};
```

modeNum gives you either a number or a string so try '777' to see if that does anything?

Comment: Tried that too, no luck.  However, if I do `exec('chmod 0777 /dir')` this does work...